# Azure SSIS Catalog not present in IntegrationServices Object

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, ssis

I have a SQL database in Azure with SSIS activated. The SSISDB is visible in SQL Server Management Studio and I can deploy packages without issue using the SSMS wizard.

[SSISDB catalog in SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAQY0.png)

But when I try do deploy my packages via Powershell the IntegrationServices object contains no catalog.

The powershell code

```
    $server.ConnectionContext.Connect()
    Log-Debug "Databases names : $($server.Databases | Select Name | Out-String)"
    $IntegrationServices = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices" $server
    Log-Debug "$($integrationServices | Out-String)"
```

and the corresponding log :

[SSISDB visible but catalogs list empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRnpA.png)

As one can see, the $server object correctly detects the SSIS database, but the IntegrationServices Catalog list is empty.

How is this possible ? A missing role on my user ?
The script was tested successfully on another SQL server installed on premises

Comment: *"How is this possible ? A missing role on my user ?"* What permissions/roles does the `USER` have on the `SSISDB` database?

Comment: I vaguely recall that this works differently in Azure because system databases (which designate these catalogs)  are inaccessible. So... hardcode to SSISDB. No one ever calls this database a different name, it really isn't worth the trouble of trying to make it dynamic

Comment: @Larnu my user has the role ssis_admin on SSISDB